# set slice in pandas date-index dataframe with number position for row and label for column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Consider the dataframe

```
                    name1   name2  randomSetOfColumns name3 randomSetOfColumns
Date        
...                                                 
2001-02-22 15:15:00 200     300     ...                1      ...
2001-02-22 15:20:00 201     301     ...                2      ...
...
```

I want to change the values in rows between 20 and 30 in column "name3". With ix being deprecated, I don't know how to mix numerical row index and label column index.

Comment: do you mean something like this?, `df.iloc[20:30, 'name3'] = 5`

Comment: @PrakashDahal that does not work. ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

Comment: Yeah, it should have been index of the name3 instead of name3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Combining positional and label-based indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#combining-positional-and-label-based-indexing):

```
df.loc[df.index[20:31], 'name3']
```

or

```
df.iloc[20:31, df.columns.get_loc('name3')]
```

to select rows 20 through 30 (including 30).

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the 2nd one but the first one is shorter.